# Compute 3D vertex at end of vector of known length

Tags: math, 3d

I'm trying to project a vector from said vertex to unknown vertex at the end of
that vector.

The knowns: Length of vector, starting vertex coordinates, angles (yaw,roll,pitch).
Unknowns: Terminating vertex coordinates at end of vector.

In 2D I can accomplish it in this manner:

```
 Target.X = Source.X + (sin(Facing*DEG2RAD)*Distance);
 Target.Y = Source.Y - (cos(Facing*DEG2RAD)*Distance);
```

Matrices seem to be overkill. I have something working feebly for 3D, but it's inaccurate which makes me believe I do not have all of the appropriate elements of the overall formula.

```
 Target.Z = Source.Z - (sin(Pitch*DEG2RAD)*Distance);
```

Ref: Facing/Pitch are in degrees (multiplied by DEG2RAD which is pi/180).

Any/all help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: This might be of some use http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_angles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to correct the x and y coordinates (project them back onto the x/y plane):

```
Target.X = Source.X + Distance * cos(Pitch * DEG2RAD) * sin(Facing * DEG2RAD);
Target.Y = Source.Y - Distance * cos(Pitch * DEG2RAD) * cos(Facing * DEG2RAD);
Target.Z = Source.Z - Distance * sin(Pitch * DEG2RAD);
```

Comment: That is awesome. I plugged that in and it freakin worked. Thanks man. :D